# Sending localStorage variables through the jQuery Ajax function without it being in the url

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, local-storage

Good day,

I would just like to know if there is a way of sending localStorage variables through the Ajax function without it being in the url. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../pages/profile.php",
    data: localStorage.email,
    dataType: 'json'
    success: function(result)
    {     
        //document.location.replace('../pages/main.php');
    },
    error: function()
    {
        alert('An Error has occured, please try again.');
    }
});
```

The return type from the php will be JSON in this case, as needed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
data: localStorage.email,
```

to

```
data: {email: localStorage.getItem('email')}
```

So that the `data` is in proper JSON format, and using (I believe) the correct way to retrieve an item from `localStorage`.