# online offline and offline synchronization in php

Tags: php, tags

I want to create a button in my page in php which can sync and update the databases from localhost to server and server to localhost.  Localhosts are having their own user ID and Password.  I mean, If the internet is not working they can update their database offline and when there is internet they can update their database in server and at the same time the updated database from server should be updated in localhost also.

Comment: online offline and offline synchronization ? your title confused me.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `localStorage` when the browser goes offline:

1. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html
2. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Then later on you should use AJAX after your browser establishes the Internet connection again, so you can send the `localStorage` contents to your server:

1. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
2. [Sending localStorage variables through the jQuery Ajax function without it being in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931039/sending-localstorage-variables-through-the-jquery-ajax-function-without-it-being)
3. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP